# SQL Return only 1 row per unique id in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried all kinds of different ways to query this but just can't seem to get exactly what I want...  What I use below works GREAT with 1 exception...  I need to have the query only return 1 row PER UNIQUE ID.  At the bottom is an example of what I'm looking to get in the end.

**My current query:**

```
SELECT
  T.id,
  T.request_type,
  T.created_timestamp,
  T.status,
  T.subject,
  P.id,
  P.created_timestamp,
  P.created_by_user,
  P.post
FROM request_threads T
INNER JOIN request_posts P
  ON T.id = P.id
WHERE T.created_by_user = 2
  AND P.created_by_user != (
    SELECT MAX(P2.created_timestamp)
    FROM request_posts P2 WHERE id = T.id
    )
ORDER BY P.created_timestamp DESC
```

**My current query results:**

`id  request_type    created_timestamp   status  subject id  created_timestamp   created_by_user post
4   7   2011-11-08 10:50:57.440 7   Request 4 blah black    4   2011-11-14 17:44:16.603 3   Changed status to Closed.
4   7   2011-11-08 10:50:57.440 7   Request 4 blah black    4   2011-11-14 17:44:07.060 3   Test for caps and no punct!
4   7   2011-11-08 10:50:57.440 7   Request 4 blah black    4   2011-11-14 17:43:36.797 3   New formated post with a capital first letter and a period at the end.
4   7   2011-11-08 10:50:57.440 7   Request 4 blah black    4   2011-11-14 13:42:27.707 3   Changed status to Pending.  Just testing...      test again      Blah
2   7   2011-11-07 14:53:01.410 7   Request 2 blah green    2   2011-11-08 13:05:23.183 3   Changed status to Closed.
4   7   2011-11-08 10:50:57.440 7   Request 4 blah black    4   2011-11-08 10:50:57.527 2   This is the 1st yellow post for four
2   7   2011-11-07 14:53:01.410 7   Request 2 blah green    2   2011-11-07 14:53:01.420 2   This is the 1st green post for two`

**The results I hope to get:**
(note I want the oldest created_timestamp from the request_posts table)

`id  request_type    created_timestamp   status  subject id  created_timestamp   created_by_user post
4   7   2011-11-08 10:50:57.440 7   Request 4 blah black    4   2011-11-14 17:44:16.603 3   Changed status to Closed.
2   7   2011-11-07 14:53:01.410 7   Request 2 blah green    2   2011-11-08 13:05:23.183 3   Changed status to Closed.`

Comment: Is created_timestamp guaranteed to be unique per ID? If not how do you want to handle ties? Use galador if you want more than one record to return for ties. Use Alex's answer when you want to arbitrarily pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want the oldest row from the posts table, so you should be able to get the results you want by changing your `WHERE` clause a bit:

```
SELECT 
    T.id,
    T.request_type,
    T.created_timestamp,
    T.status,
    T.subject,
    P.id,
    P.created_timestamp,
    P.created_by_user,
    P.post
FROM request_threads T
INNER JOIN request_posts P
    ON T.id = P.id
WHERE T.created_by_user = 2
  AND P.created_timestamp = 
        (SELECT MIN(P2.created_timestamp)
         FROM request_posts P2
         WHERE id = T.id)
ORDER BY P.created_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: This works exactly as what I expected in the end.  Thanks!

Wow...  At one point I came so close to this same thing...  I'll get it at some point.  ;)

Comment: Oops!  Forgot to add, I needed to change the MIN( to MAX( ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY p.created_timestamp DESC) AS row
        , T.id AS tID, T.request_type, T.created_timestamp AS c_timestamp, T.status, T.subject
        , P.id AS pID, P.created_timestamp AS p_timestamp, P.created_by_user, P.post
    FROM request_threads T 
    JOIN request_posts P
        ON T.id = P.id
    WHERE T.created_by_user = 2
    ) x
WHERE row = 1
```

Comment: And definitely check that where clause, doesn't look like what you wanted to me.

Comment: This one returns an error...
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this part of your where clause:

```
AND P.created_by_user != (SELECT MAX(P2.created_timestamp) FROM request_posts P2 WHERE id = T.id)
```

You are comparing a user id to a date there.
I think you may want to replace this clause with this:

```
AND P.created_timestamp = (SELECT MIN(P2.created_timestamp) FROM request_posts P2 WHERE id = T.id)
```

This way you will grab, for each **id** value, the oldest created record from request_posts.

Comment: Yea at this point I don't know what I was thinking using created_by_user there...  :/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to add a subselect on the created timestamp to make sure you get the single record.

```
SELECT T.id, T.request_type, T.created_timestamp, T.status, T.subject, P.id, P.created_timestamp, P.created_by_user, P.post
FROM request_threads T 
    INNER JOIN request_posts P
        ON T.id = P.id
        AND P.created_timestamp = (SELECT MIN(S.created_timestamp) FROM request_posts S WHERE P.id = S.id)
WHERE
T.created_by_user = 2
    AND P.created_by_user != (SELECT MAX(P2.created_timestamp) FROM request_posts P2 WHERE id = T.id)
ORDER BY P.created_timestamp DESC
```

Edited for oldest = MIN  :-)

Comment: This works well too IF you change the MIN to MAX near the top.  ;)  Currently it gives me the first post and I wanted the last post.  (oldest timestamp)